# Mute Video Player Package Console Messages

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there a simple effective way to totally mute Video Player Console Messages, trying to make a rather complex app and I need to see my debug messages, which is impossible considering the hundreds of messages Video Player dumps in the run console , I am using Android Studio 4.1.1 and video_player ^1.0.1:

```
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 3)
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.50956130483689
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.50956130483689
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.532058492688414
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.532058492688414
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.55455568053993
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.55455568053993
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.577052868391455
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.577052868391455
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 8922): bufferpool2 0xaaa8b198 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 10/90858 (fetch/transfer)
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.59955005624297
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.59955005624297
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.62204724409449
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.62204724409449
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.64454443194601
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.64454443194601
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.66704161979752
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.66704161979752
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.68953880764904
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.68953880764904
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.712035995500564
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 8922): bufferpool2 0xaaa8b198 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 5(40960 size) used buffers - 1/7 (recycle/alloc) - 10/91111 (fetch/transfer)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 1)
I/flutter ( 8922): 43.712035995500564
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 1)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 3)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 2)
D/CCodecBuffers( 8922): [c2.android.aac.decoder#400:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make VideoPlayer widget as external widget outside Build method; Also please don't forget to close controller

---

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _videoController.dispose();
  }
```

---

```
    Widget _videoView() {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: _videoController.value.size?.width ?? 0,
          height: _videoController.value.size?.height ?? 0,
          child: VideoPlayer(_videoController),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    _videoView(),
             ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```